# pbox not showing up

Tags: boxes, box

This is what I have:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pbox}
\begin{document}
$A= \pbox[center][1cm]{3cm}{B}$
\end{document}
```

When generating the pdf it goes like "A =       " without any box, what am I doing wrong?

this is what it looks like,

[image: the result]

and this is what I'm looking for,
[image: this is what I look for, if anything come up to one of you]

Comment: `$A= \pbox[c]{3cm}{B}$` works as expected. I cannot find the syntax you propose in the manual.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I added an image, I'm using VerbTex in android, could it be the package I downloaded? the image looks annoying, sorry for not cropping.

Comment: @Sebastiano I was using `\fbox`, but it wouldn't let me resize it, and `\framebox` isn't aligned with the line, it grows vertically.. so pbox would have centered.

Comment: @BrunoStühler You can also include phantom words to have a blank space. I have read the manual but I think, humbly, that this package it is not very important and there is another ways to obtain your result.

Comment: @BrunoStühler Ah...if you change the code, in differents times, we not help you :-).

Comment: Your's is a typical XY-question. The answer to your present question is “replace `[center]` with `[c]` (or remove it altogether). The answer to the question you have in your mind is obviously very different.

Comment: @egreg the problem is that `A= \pbox[c][1cm]{3cm}{B}$` doesn't display a box, at least not in the device I'm using. For some reason switching center for c, resulted in B showing up in there, so it gets A=B, I mean, I can right that, so the fbox would be useless.

Comment: Nothing in the manual of `pbox` suggests that it is able to make frames. The frames you see in it are just to display the code used for producing the result shown at the left.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this you do not need any package. For the numbers in circles you can use `pifont`, though. The usage of the `\NumBox` command is explained in the example code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pifont}
\newcommand\NumBox[3][1.8em]{\fbox{\begin{tabular}{@{}p{#3}@{}}
\ding{\the\numexpr171+#2}$\vcenter{\vspace{#1}}$\\
\end{tabular}}}
\begin{document}
\subsection*{Usage}
\texttt{\textbackslash NumBox[$\langle\mbox{height}\rangle$]\{$\langle\mbox{number}\rangle$\}%
\{$\langle\mbox{width}\rangle$\}}

\bigskip


\noindent
$\NumBox{1}{3cm}\le x\le \NumBox{2}{3cm}$

\bigskip

\noindent
$\NumBox[3em]{3}{3cm}\le y\le \NumBox[3em]{4}{4cm}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

There is of course also the possibility to use `circledsteps`, which opens the possibility of using pgf keys. The syntax becomes then much more intuitive (IMHO). (Of course, one could then also draw the box with pgf...)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circledsteps}
\pgfkeys{/Bruno/.cd,width/.initial=3cm,height/.initial=1.8em}
\newcommand\NumBox[2][]{\pgfkeys{/Bruno/.cd,#1}
\fbox{\begin{tabular}{@{}p{\pgfkeysvalueof{/Bruno/width}}@{}}
\Circled{#2}$\vcenter{\vspace{\pgfkeysvalueof{/Bruno/height}}}$\\
\end{tabular}}}
\begin{document}
\subsection*{Usage}
\texttt{\textbackslash NumBox[$\langle\mbox{keys}\rangle$]\{$\langle\mbox{number}\rangle$\}}

\bigskip


\noindent
$\NumBox{1}\le x\le \NumBox{2}$

\bigskip

\noindent
$\NumBox[height=3em]{3}\le y\le \NumBox[height=3em,width=4cm]{4}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm using pifont also :-) +1

Comment: Oh my xD wish I could hug you friend, thank you for your time, that's amazing. btw, I'm building a question paper sorted by subject, so I can study for an entrance exam :)

Comment: @BrunoStühler You have given the green light to the best answer. I'm much simpler because I'm inexperienced.

Comment: @Sebastiano yeah xD it's a superb resolution from Schrödinger, straightforward as well, we should both absorb

Comment: @BrunoStühler I am a humble user and give to Caesar what is Caesar's.

Comment: @Sebastiano I am just a cat. Thanks for your kind words, grazie mille!

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat No, no...you're a human being like all the others but with excellent skills. All of us must rediscover that we must be united and strong here in this community and I hope that this very bad time for everyone will pass quickly.

Answer (score 3):

I must admit that I am not as good as many other users ... but after many attempts I reached the goal ... wow ... and I also have the numbers aligned ahaahah.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{pifont}
\newcommand{\largebox}{\phantom{\begin{bmatrix}
    x_{11}       & x_{12} \\
    x_{21}       & x_{22} 
    \end{bmatrix}}}
\begin{document}
\[\boxed{\text{\ding{172}}\largebox} \leqq x \leqq \boxed{\text{\ding{173}}\largebox}\]
\[\boxed{\text{\ding{174}}\largebox}\leqq y \leqq \boxed{\text{\ding{175}}\largebox}\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes that looks neat.. but it hasn't a height-width option has it? thank you.

Comment: @BrunoStühler No no please. I'm searching to change my answer or delete it. I'm all for fairness. I'm trying to create a big box that creates your final image. Could you please remove the green tick? Thank you.

Comment: I've removed the green tick :)

Comment: It's amazing, I shall study both formats :) and well, knowledge in such matters.. I can tell you hehe it's always impressive..